# Cual es la unidad de medida que devuelve width y height en una imagen en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con la obtencion de tamaño de alto y ancho de una imagen

Parto de una imagen que se cuales son sus tamaños

**ancho 2160px**
**alto 3840px**

Mi código en javacript

```js
//Quitamos el ancho y  alto que tiene en el navegador para obtener el tamaño original
 $('#imagen').removeAttr("width"); 
$('#imagen').removeAttr("height");
alert('ancho'+$('#imagen').width()+'X alto'+$('#imagen').height());
```

retorna la siguiente 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pregunta cuales es la unidad de medida que retorna?

Comment: El valor es en pixels

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro los pixeles no pueden ser decimales

Comment: @ReneLimon - Desde cuando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación de jQuery para [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) (y paralelamente para [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)) se especifica que los valores devueltos son en pixels pero sin unidad (negrita puesta por mí para resaltar):

> The difference between `.css( "height" )` and `.height()` is that **the latter returns a unit-less pixel value** (for example, `400`) while the former returns a value with units intact (for example, `400px`). The `.height()` method is recommended when an element's height needs to be used in a mathematical calculation.

Que se puede traducir como:

> La diferencia entre `.css( "height" )` y`.height()` es que **este último devuelve  como valor pixels sin unidades** (por ejemplo, `400`) mientras que el primero devuelve el valor con unidades intacto (por ejemplo, `400px`). El uso de `.height()` es recomendable cuando la altura del elemento se necesita para realizar cálculos matemáticos.